# Can't boot Windows XP after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-xp

So I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows XP, and I played with it for a like an hour. When I wanted to go back to Windows, I chose the Windows option in the GRUB screen. It just gives a black screen and goes back to grub. I tried boot-repair as I've seen in some other post that it could resolve the problem, but it's all the same. Nothing changed. I can use Ubuntu but not Windows. Can someone please tell me how I can solve this? Thanks.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1231432/

Comment: Just a wild, shot-in-the-dark thing, but look at lines 263-266: `1 disks with OS, 2 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.`

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Its not the first something like this happens and I normally just do a clean install and voila. This time I'm seeing if someone can point me to some solution because i'm just tired of having to config windows all over again after giving linux another try :(

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a Windows XP CD and got o recovery mode and in the command line write the command `fixboot` then restart

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: backup the current boot record from within Ubuntu using `dd if=/dev/sda of=/ubuntu.bin bs=446 count=1`. Copy `ubuntu.bin` to `c:\ubuntu` of your Windows partition, you should be able to mount it by simply starting the file manager within Ubuntu and mounting the Windows XP partition.  You may also accomplish this by copying `/boot/grub/boot.img` to `c:\ubuntu\ubuntu.bin`.

step 2: boot from your Windows XP CD. Go to recovery mode and at the command line type `fixboot` then restart.

step 3: add and entry for Ubuntu into the `boot.ini`, `C:\ubuntu\ubuntu.bin="Ubuntu 12.04"`.  You should then be able to boot both operating systems.