# booting issues booting windows XP after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my system, Windows XP won't boot any more. Ubuntu starts ok however.

When starting Windows in the Grub menu, it give's an error:

```
ERROR: UNKNOWN FILESYSTEM.
GRUB RESCUE
```

I've tried to resolve it using boot-repair but with no result. Also tried the booterrorfix as suggested but no result.

Boot-repairs logs the following info:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7079160/

Your support is much appreciated.

Comment: Asked and answered here.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/193877/cant-boot-windows-xp-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

From the boot-repair log,

```
Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda1 
and looks at sector 128708312 of the same hard drive 
for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive. No errors found 
in the Boot Parameter Block.
```

Grub installed in the boot sector of `dev/sda1` Windows Xp partition.So you have to repair your windows boot files and then you have to run boot-repair again.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/381603/202806) to repair your Windows boot files and  reinstall grub on `/dev/sda` disk.